# Default Overheating Behavior

Tags: linux, linux-mint, overheating

What is the default behavior of Linux Mint when the computer gets too hot?  Shutdown?  Logging out?

I've not been able to find this information elsewhere; the OS may not even do anything when this happens.  Just interested in what happens, I'm troubleshooting an issue and was trying to check this off the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of issue has nothing to do with the Operating System you are running.   You could install some sort of monitoring software that could set off an alarm when your CPU reaches some tempature - but a vanilla install of any Microsoft or Linux OS is not going to concern itself with such matters.

If you have a CPU that is overheating, the first symptom you will notice is that your computer will just shut off without warning.   Intel CPUs (and I would imagine AMD as well, but I am not 100% on that) have a built in mechanism to protect themselves from damage.   When you are referring to CPU overheating, the following terms are commonly used to explain thermal (heating) conditions

- **Tcase Max** is the maximum temperature that the Tcase sensor should reach. Both Tcase and the thermal specification information can be found on the Intel web site.
- **Tjunction Max** is the maximum temperature the cores can reach before thermal throttling is activated. Thermal throttling happens when the processor exceeds the maximum temperature. The processor shuts itself off in order to prevent permanent damage.

Some other common things you might notice if you are experiencing overheating are

- **Loud or Unusual Fan Noise** Most computers have two fans, one fan that cools the power supply, and one that cools the processor. If a fan starts to make unusual whirring, clicking, clunking, or a musical sound or beep, the fan might be failing. If the fan is the problem, always replace, never repair.
- **BSOD**  (Windows Only) If a fan does fail, the computer might boot up properly but then start to overheat. The most common result is a blue screen. If you keep getting a Windows* error and a blue screen, check the cooling fan and the air flow coming or going from your computer.
- **Reboot or Shutdown Unexpectedly** To prevent damage to components, the computer shuts down or reboots if it senses an overheating issue. The system might reboot every few minutes until the problem is resolved. This often occurs if your system CPU is over-clocked (sped up past the recommended speed limits). The BIOS usually reports if a thermal event has occurred
- **Non-Fan Overheating** Under normal working conditions, if all fans are functioning and a CPU still overheats, replace the thermal interface material (TIM) between the heatsink and processor. The TIM eventually hardens on most systems. See a computer technician, or purchase professional grade TIM and replace it yourself. Carefully follow all instructions and warnings. See How to apply [Thermal Interface Material (TIM).](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-030329.htm)

Could you edit your post to let everyone know if you are running an Intel or AMD CPU?   What sort of temps are you getting?   What is the exactly make/model of CPU?   If your CPU is within the range of acceptable temperatures, you might be experiencing power issues, grounding issues, faulty motherboard, etc..

Since you are running Linux, try the 'lscpu' command and post the output here.   I am not very familar with Mint myself, so I am not sure if this is installed by default or not on that distro.   If not, use whatever package manager Mint uses to install lscpu and post the results here.

Comment: My temps are around 40-50c and don't waver much.  I just wanted to ensure that there wasn't any sort of default behavior that I wasn't accounting for.  Thanks for the clarification that Linux Mint doesn't attempt to do anything by default.  I saw they had the default `sensor` command, so I didn't know if it did more by default.

Comment: *"set off an alarm"* or take an action such as gracefully shutting down the computer, putting it to sleep or hibernate, increasing fan speed and/or throttling the processor down, or even more peculiar actions like sending an email or SMS alert.

Comment: Yeah but you need to configure the alarms in order to have anything happen.   BTW 40-50C is 104F-122F which is well within the range of acceptable CPU temps.   My Haswell CPU seems to idle at around 100-109F, which is considerably hotter than my Sandy bridge CPU which idles at 89-93F.   When you start hitting around 180F (82C), that is when you should start to worry.

Comment: OP - can you mark this as the answer or edit your question so someone can correctly answer it?

Comment: Sorry, comment notifications are weird.